# How do I create a test structure in Android Studio?

Tags: android, testing, junit, android-studio

I have a project that was recently migrated to Android Studio (and gradle). I now want to create a suite of tests for it. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this in Android Studio (it was so easy in Eclipse ADT).

I have the following file structure:
[image: project structure]

My build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'libs'}
}

sourceSets {
    testLocal {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.larswerkman.holocolorpicker:holocolorpicker:1.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    testLocalCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    testLocalCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.0.1.2'
    testLocalCompile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r6'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        testPackageName "com.glasstowerstudios.stainedglass.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
}

task localTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.testLocal.output.classesDir

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')

        sourceSets.testLocal.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn localTest
```

The test that I created is called `AllTests.java`, and it just has a single assertion in it right now (I'm just trying to get the test framework setup before I implement the actual test logic:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

package com.glasstowerstudios.stainedglass.test;

public class AllTests extends TestCase {
  public void setUp() {

  }

  public void tearDown() {

  }

  public void testStartup() {
    Assert.assertEquals(true, true);
  }
}
```

When I run the build it succeeds, even if I do `gradle localTest` from the command line. However, inside of Android Studio, when I right-click on AllTests.java and select `Run AllTests`, I get the following error:

```
Error running 'AllTests':
Class 'AllTests' not found in module 'stainedglass'
```

I'm thinking this has something to do with how I created the test (created the directories one at a time inside of test/ and then created the file via `New` -> `File`. So, I think perhaps it just simply isn't added to the module in the same way that say, the `src/main/java` directory is (you can see this in the diagram - `src/main/java` is in blue, while `src/test/java` is still orange.

What is the "right" way of creating a test structure for existing code in Android Studio?

Comment: Well, I just realized that renaming the test directory to `instrumentTest` causes my particular case to run, but the question still exists - what's the "Accepted" way to create a test structure for an existing android project in Android Studio?